# How do I prevent my HDMI-audio-only connected GPU from powering off itself?

Tags: ati, power-management, gpu, xbmc

I have a PC running Ubuntu and XBMC with the following specifications:

- CPU - AMD A6-3500 APU - Radeon(tm) HD Graphics integrated
- discrete graphics card: AMD HD6400

I got the HD6400 just to have output sound over HDMI. It all start working great, however when it's been idle for a while the sound output is lost and it seems the card has been turned off completely.

Perhaps this is a power saving feature as the graphics power is not needed, but I'd like to know if it is possible to keep the HD6400 on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to turn off Standby and Sleep for the installation, and that seems to have helped the issue. It's not a preferred workaround, but it's acceptable in my case.

It looks like the card gets turned off when entering standby mode, and doesn't get woken up when the OS is woken.